# Spannable String in Fragment

Tags: java, android, regex, android-fragments, spannablestring

Im using a `SpannableString` to color the words which match an existing string.

This works perfectly the first time the fragment is called, the words are found, matched and colored. But the second time the fragment is called, the method which checks for matches and colors the matching words fires, and from the log cat I can see the words are found and matched but not colored.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the lifecycle of the fragment and where `SpannableString` is being initialized.

I have tried to initialize the `SpannableString` in `onResume();` and in `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser);`

This is my approach

```
public class LessonOne extends ActualFragmetHolder  {

@Override
public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    addSlide(FragmentPronounce.newInstance("The cat is jumping over the     mouse"));

    addSlide(FragmentPronounce.newInstance("This house is really big"));
.....
```

FragmentPronounce.java

```
public class FragmentPronounce extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,RecognitionListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
  private static final String ARG_OPTION_ONE = "opt1";
  private SpannableString hashText;
  ....


public static FragmentPronounce newInstance(String option1) {

  FragmentPronounce sampleSlide = new FragmentPronounce();

  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  args.putString(ARG_OPTION_ONE, option1);
  sampleSlide.setArguments(args);

  return sampleSlide;
 }


@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 ....

 if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().size() != 0) {
  option1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_OPCTION_ONE);

 }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pronounce_material, container, false);

final TextView the_question = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_user_must_say);
if (theQuestion != 0) {
  the_question.setText(theQuestion);
}
 //mic button
 fabMic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ///starts listening for speech and does its thing
    ///Im using my own custom speech recognition which works fine
    speech.startListening(recognizerIntent);
    ////check for OnResults()
 }
}

@Override
public void onResults(Bundle results) {
//if its a OnResults is fine then
 methodToCheckAnswer(results);
 ....
}

private void methodToCheckAnswer(Bundle results) {
 //checks answer and calls method which counts and colors words in string
 countAndColorWords();
}

//This is the method which check and colors, it triggers fine every time  fragment is called, but it only colors the word the first time is called in the fragment's life cycle
private void countAndColorWords(){
 String strRight = rightanswer;
    .....
    the_question = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.text_user_says);
    the_question.setText(theQuestion);
    System.out.println("The question's TEXT" + String.valueOf(the_question.getText().toString()) + "Tokens counted" + tokensCounted + "Option1" + option1 + "What was spoken " + userAnswered);
    hashText = SpannableString.valueOf(the_question.getText().toString());
    System.out.println("hashText Value "+hashText+  "Right Answer "+ rightanswer);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(strRight);
    Matcher usermatcher = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(userAnswered);
    int groupCounted = 0;
    groupCounted += matcher.groupCount()+1;
    Log.d(TAG, "The position number of groups:"+groupCounted +" "+userAnswered);
    int rightAnswerCount = matcher.groupCount();
    int userAnswerCount = usermatcher.groupCount();
    String rightAnswer;
    String userAnswer;
    int contadorGroup = 0;;
    int matchCounter =0;
    contadorGroup += matcher.groupCount() + 1;

    while (matcher.find() && usermatcher.find()) {
      System.out.println(matcher.start() + ":" + matcher.group());

      rightAnswer = matcher.group();
      userAnswer = usermatcher.group();
      rightAnswerCount += matcher.groupCount();
      userAnswerCount += usermatcher.groupCount();
      String check = "";
      for (int i = 0; i <= rightAnswerCount && i <= userAnswerCount; i++) {

        if (matcher.group(i).equalsIgnoreCase(usermatcher.group(i))) {//matcher.group(i) == usermatcher.group(i)
          matchCounter++;
          check = matcher.group(i);

          hashText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#64DD17")), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), i);
        }

      }

    }
    //hashText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#64DD17")), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), palabraColor);
    the_question.setText(hashText);
}
```

Sorry for spaghetti code, tried cleaning it up best I could after trying 100 different things.